# Probability Choosing At Least Some Number of Balls

Tags: probability

So, I have a problem which we can imagine as a bag and balls example, in which we would have 247500 blue balls and 2500 white balls. If we choose 8500 balls without replacement, what is the probability that at least 5 white balls are chosen?

This is how I am calculating at least 1 white ball is chosen:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-(nCr(247500,8500)%2FnCr(250000,8500))

How can I calculate this to be at least 5 instead of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-[`sum[binom[2500,k]*binom[247500,8500-k]/binom[250000, 8500],{k,0,4}]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%5Bbinom%5B2500,k%5D*binom%5B247500,8500-k%5D%2Fbinom%5B250000,8500%5D,%7Bk,0,4%7D%5D)

$$\mathsf P(X\geq 5) = 1-\sum_{k=0}^4 \dfrac{\dbinom{2500}{k}~\dbinom{247500}{8500-k}}{\dbinom{250000}{8500}} ~\approx~ 1- 4.8369×10^{-32}$$

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me, the answer should be very close to 1. And when I increase 247500 the probability should decrease which doesn't happen?

Comment: Subtract from 1.

Comment: Perfect thanks. But something a bit strange is when I change the numbers a bit to make 25 white balls instead of 2500 the probability of choosing >= 5 is somehow greater than choosing at least 1: 1-sum[binom[25,k]*binom[249975,8500-k]/binom[250000,8500],{k,0,5}] < 1-5((nCr(249975,8500)/nCr(250000,8500))) = False

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ the number of white balls choosen. You are asking for $P(X\ge 5)=1-P(X<5)=1-\sum_{k=0}^4P(X=k)$.

Fix $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Then $P(X=k)=\frac{\binom{2,500}{k}\binom{247,500}{8,500-k}}{\binom{250,000}{8500}}$.

Thus $\sum_{k=0}^4P(X=k)=\sum_{k=0}^4\frac{\binom{2,500}{k}\binom{247,500}{8,500-k}}{\binom{250,000}{8500}}=4.836\times 10^{-32}$. Therefore $P(X\ge 5)=1-4.836\times 10^{-32}$